# How to set event handlers in android compound view via XML?

Tags: android

I'm creating a simple compound view which contains a button and a text view.
I would like to set the click event listener of the button via XML. How can I do this?

To clarify, lets assume that I have the following XML

```
<com.example.app.CompoundView
    custom:onIntenalButtonClick="myClickEventHandler" />
```

I can achieve this behavior via code by adding a setOnClickEventListener or similar to my compound view, and register it to the click event of the internal button myself.

```
public class CompoundView extends LinearLayout {
    private Button m_btnCustomButton;
    ...
    public CompoundView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        ...
        m_btnCustomButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMyCustomButton);
        ...
    }
    ...
    public setCustomClickEvent(OnClickListener cListener) {
        m_btnCustomButton.setOnClickListener(cListener);
    }
    ...
}
```

My current idea was to add a custom string attribute and activate a method with the same name using reflection.

Thanks in advance,
Kfir

Comment: why you putting onclick in xml. put it in java code

Comment: yes, reflection is the only way for doing that, but why? its much slower

Comment: I want it to be consistent to the views provided by the android system where you can do this via XML. How is it implemented by android? also by using reflection?

Comment: yes this is the only way

Answer (score 0):

pskink answered the question by saying that it is only possible to achieve this behavior by using reflection.